# Call to undefined method Database::prepare()

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton, pdo

from http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

```
###### config.ini ######
db_driver=mysql
db_user=root
db_password=924892xp

[dsn]
host=localhost
port=3306
dbname=localhost

[db_options]
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=set names utf8

[db_attributes]
ATTR_ERRMODE=ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
############

<?php class Database {
    private static $link = null ;

    private static function getLink ( ) {
        if ( self :: $link ) {
            return self :: $link ;
        }

        $ini = _BASE_DIR . "config.ini" ;
        $parse = parse_ini_file ( $ini , true ) ;

        $driver = $parse [ "db_driver" ] ;
        $dsn = "${driver}:" ;
        $user = $parse [ "db_user" ] ;
        $password = $parse [ "db_password" ] ;
        $options = $parse [ "db_options" ] ;
        $attributes = $parse [ "db_attributes" ] ;

        foreach ( $parse [ "dsn" ] as $k => $v ) {
            $dsn .= "${k}=${v};" ;
        }

        self :: $link = new PDO ( $dsn, $user, $password, $options ) ;

        foreach ( $attributes as $k => $v ) {
            self :: $link -> setAttribute ( constant ( "PDO::{$k}" )
                , constant ( "PDO::{$v}" ) ) ;
        }

        return self :: $link ;
    }

    public static function __callStatic ( $name, $args ) {
        $callback = array ( self :: getLink ( ), $name ) ;
        return call_user_func_array ( $callback , $args ) ;
    }
} ?>

<?php // examples
$stmt = Database :: prepare ( "SELECT 'something' ;" ) ;
$stmt -> execute ( ) ;
var_dump ( $stmt -> fetchAll ( ) ) ;
$stmt -> closeCursor ( ) ;
?>
```

What have I done wrong, or was this example code wrong?
Call to undefined method Database::prepare() on line 167

Comment: Just curious, since all the code you posted here is taken directly from the link you provided, do you have the ini file, and do you actually have a database to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `prepare` in your Database class. That belongs to the PDO object that you are storing as `$link`.

What you are probably looking for is

```
Database :: $link->prepare(...)
```

**Update re your comment**: You're right, didn't catch that. `__callStatic` is available in [PHP >= 5.3.0 only](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) - do you have the right version?

Comment: Isn't that what:     public static function __callStatic ( $name, $args ) {
        $callback = array ( self :: getLink ( ), $name ) ;
        return call_user_func_array ( $callback , $args ) ;
    }
 should do?

Comment: I'll select you answer in 4 mins (need to wait)

Comment: @Johnny I don't think so, no. Not in a static context.

Answer (score 0):

as the error message says: there is noch public static method named "prepare" in you database-class...